# How to import a .so Library in Android.mk when i build APK

Tags: android, makefile, ndk-build, .so, android.mk

I have this problem: I have to build my app using the Android.mk file and I have to insert the library "libcom_google_ase_Exec.so" inside the final apk, but I can't do it. What I get is an APK that doesn't contain the library and therefore the app doesn't work.

The code for the Android.mk I'm currently using is:

```
#ifneq ($(TARGET_BUILD_PDK), true)

LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := com_google_ase_Exec
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/libcom_google_ase_Exec.so
    
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := Sshd
LOCAL_PRIVATE_PLATFORM_APIS := true

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := samples
LOCAL_USE_AAPT2 := true

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, app/src/main/java)
LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)/app/src/main/res/
LOCAL_MANIFEST_FILE := app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
# LOCAL_ASSETS_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)/assets

LOCAL_STATIC_ANDROID_LIBRARIES += \
    android-support-v13 \
    android-support-v7-cardview \
    android-support-v7-recyclerview \
    android-support-annotations
    

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := \
    libsshd-core \
    libsshd-common \
    libsshd-scp \
    libsshd-sftp \
    libslf4j \
    libbcpkix \
    libbcprov
    

LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true

LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := disabled

LOCAL_DEX_PREOPT := false


LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libcom_google_ase_Exec
#LOCAL_PREBUILTS := com_google_ase_Exec

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := \
    libsshd-core:app/libs/sshd-core-2.8.0.jar \
    libsshd-common:app/libs/sshd-common-2.8.0.jar \
    libsshd-scp:app/libs/sshd-scp-2.8.0.jar \
    libsshd-sftp:app/libs/sshd-sftp-2.8.0.jar \
    libslf4j:app/libs/slf4j-api-1.7.35.jar \
    libbcpkix:app/libs/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.70.jar \
    libbcprov:app/libs/bcprov-jdk15on-1.70.jar

include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)


#include $(call all-makefiles-under, $(LOCAL_PATH))

#endif
```

The folder structure within my project is as follows:
In the root i have:
--> /app and Android.mk
In the app folder i have:
--> app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/libcom_google_ase_Exec.so

How can i change the Android.mk file to import the .so library in the final APK?

Answer (score 0):

```
#ifneq ($(TARGET_BUILD_PDK), true)

LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := Sshd
LOCAL_PRIVATE_PLATFORM_APIS := true

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := samples
LOCAL_USE_AAPT2 := true

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, app/src/main/java)
LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)/app/src/main/res/
LOCAL_MANIFEST_FILE := app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
# LOCAL_ASSETS_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)/assets

LOCAL_STATIC_ANDROID_LIBRARIES += \
    android-support-v13 \
    android-support-v7-cardview \
    android-support-v7-recyclerview \
    android-support-annotations
    

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := \
    libsshd-core \
    libsshd-common \
    libsshd-scp \
    libsshd-sftp \
    libslf4j \
    libbcpkix \
    libbcprov

LOCAL_JNI_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libcom_google_ase_Exec
#LOCAL_MULTILIB = 32
    
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true
LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := disabled
#LOCAL_UNINSTALLABLE_MODULE := true
#LOCAL_DEX_PREOPT := false


include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform

LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := \
    libsshd-core:app/libs/sshd-core-2.8.0.jar \
    libsshd-common:app/libs/sshd-common-2.8.0.jar \
    libsshd-scp:app/libs/sshd-scp-2.8.0.jar \
    libsshd-sftp:app/libs/sshd-sftp-2.8.0.jar \
    libslf4j:app/libs/slf4j-api-1.7.35.jar \
    libbcpkix:app/libs/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.70.jar \
    libbcprov:app/libs/bcprov-jdk15on-1.70.jar

include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libcom_google_ase_Exec
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := samples
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/libcom_google_ase_Exec.so
#LOCAL_MULTILIB = 32
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := SHARED_LIBRARIES
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX = .so
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)

#include $(call all-makefiles-under, $(LOCAL_PATH))

#endif
```

I solved in this way, i build a 64bit version.
If u need a 32bit version u can uncomment all LOCAL_MULTILIB = 32.

Answer (score 0):

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := AndroidMediaShell
LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := app/$(LOCAL_MODULE).apk
LOCAL_PREBUILT_JNI_LIBS := lib/example.so
LOCAL_MODULE_TARGET_ARCH := arm or arm64 or x86
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := PRESIGNED
LOCAL_OVERRIDES_PACKAGES :=
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

[LOCAL_MULTILIB](https://source.android.com/docs/setup/create/64-bit-builds#module_definition_in_android_mk)